# How do I compile a theano network into an self-contained executable?

Tags: python, executable, theano

We would like to enter a competition where we would need to submit our network in the form of an executable. In one of the subcompetitions, the network will be trained by the judges, e.g.

CASE 1:

```
./train-my-network-script trainingdata.dat  #call script to train
./run-my-network input.dat      #script to run our trained network input
```

CASE 2:
and in another, we would submit a trained network that will just receive an input file, e.g.

```
./run-my-trained-net -i input.dat -o output.dat
```

How do I compile our theano-built network (whether it's an RBM or other variation) into something that can be packaged in this way without requiring the people on the other end to actually install theano?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the judge install a VM or a Docker image with Theano and your stuff installed? This would be easier in the short term.

We don't have exactly what you ask, but there is work to generate a shared library for a Theano function. This is not yet merged in Theano itself. I started this and Alberto Orlandi is continuing this. He have a working version on a branch. See this branch:

https://github.com/AlOa/Theano/commits/embed_theano

Also this mailing list discussion:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/theano-users/JtxIequsHNg/discussion

He is working to make a PR for this. But the current version do not do exactly what you want and need some work from you for the shared variables and to make this work.

What this branch do is generate a C++ shared library that depend on Python and NumPy, but not Theano.